# Maximize the score of a card game

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, machine-learning, card-games, combinatorial-game-theory

### About the game

This game consist on a deck of 24 cards. Each has a color (there are only 3 colors) and a number (from 1 to 8), and each card is unique.

Every turn you are given cards (randomly) from the deck, until you have 5 cards (you can have up to 5 cards in your hand). You can also discard cards you do not need.

The goal is to make combinations of three cards by arranging them in a sequence or by having the same number in the three cards.

When you make a combination, you get points according to a table, then those cards are discarded from your hand.

The game ends when the deck is empty, and you have no combinations left to make.

| Combination | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 1, 1, 1 | 20 |
| 2, 2, 2 | 30 |
| 3, 3, 3 | 40 |
| 4, 4, 4 | 50 |
| 5, 5, 5 | 60 |
| 6, 6, 6 | 70 |
| 7, 7, 7 | 80 |
| 8, 8, 8 | 90 |
| 1, 2, 3 | 10 |
| 2, 3, 4 | 20 |
| 3, 4, 5 | 30 |
| 4, 5, 6 | 40 |
| 5, 6, 7 | 50 |
| 6, 7, 8 | 60 |

*If the cards of the combination have the same colors there are 40 extra points. (*Note:* this happens only when the combination is a **sequence**)*.

### The Problem

I need to find an optimal action for a given state. I tried using `vanilla MCTS` but I didn't get good results.  
Do you think there is another way to see the problem and use a different approach for this game? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned the first time you posted this, you need to specify the objective here ("maximize expected outcome", "minimize worst outcome", something else?) and you need to analyze the strategy accordingly.  In principle, this looks set up for backwards induction, but you need to worry about the number of states.

Comment: Not sure I was clear:  whatever the objective function is, you can optimize the strategy via backwards induction.  That would tell you the best move given any state of you hand and the balance of the deck.  Then Monte Carlo works, since you can just employ the optimal strategy at each node.  It's possible, of course, that you can describe the strategy in some computable way without going through all this, but just looking at the scoring list makes that seem improbable.  However, since the possible states are so many, it might be difficult to run the induction.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the goal is to find the action that maximize the expected outcome, in this case the outcome is the total score. You are correct, the number of states is huge and it seems to be impossible to compute all of them in order to get the best solution.

Comment: Well, There are symmetries.  Permuting the colors has no impact on the value of a state, right?  So that's a big reduction in the state space.  Failing that, you'll need some proxy for the optimal strategy. That is, a simple function which does quite well most of the time and not too badly in the sub-optimal cases.   I suggest doing the induction with a smaller deck to get a sense.

Comment: On the one hand, even if I knew Monte Carlo trees from a giraffe, which I don't, I probably wouldn't go near such a complicated problem without first trying to attack it programmatically.  That is, (if needed) scale the problem down, perhaps cutting the deck in (1/2), and attempt to programmatically identify the best approach.  The difficulty is that this (still) seems far too cumbersome an approach.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, my next try would be machine learning, using a process similar to how Alpha-Zero was used to attack Chess.  While I could be mistaken, I suspect that *machine learning* software, compatible with vanilla PC hardware, is freely available (i.e. downloadable).  My understanding is that (for example) while Alpha Zero (Chess) knows the rules of the game, it does not (for example) understand relative values, such a bishop vs knight, or piece mobility.  So, Alpha Zero attacks Chess, without any regard for Chess fundamentals, simply by playing millions of games and *learning*. ...see next comment

Comment: Why couldn't the same approach work here?  For example, you could define *winning* to be attaining a score above $n$, where $n$ is some positive integer.  Then, you could *increase* the value of $n$, and note how the evolved strategy would change.  As one of the comments of @lulu  suggested, this approach hamstrings, because you are then maximimizing the chance of not failing, rather than maximizing expected value.  My understanding, which could be mistaken, is that the AI has to always have some explicit definition of *success*.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, you would have to *manually remedy the hamstringing* by manually manipulating the value of $n$, which defines success/failure, and then watching how the strategy evolves, and noting the win percentage at various values of $~n.$

Comment: @lulu you are right, permuting the colors has no impact on the value of a state. But I think that the amount of possible states continues being huge to compute (with a 24 cards deck). However, it could be a good starting point to test it with a smaller deck as you suggest!

Comment: @user2661923 I could give a try to Alpha-Zero. Moreover, as you said I could define winning to be a score above $n$. In this game, I consider $n \geq 400$ an excellent outcome, so I could also try to implement something like this.

Comment: $2^{24}= 16,777,216$  which is not beyond machine reach, though you might need to keep track of both a general subset and a $5$ card hand, and that's a much bigger space.  But an $18$ card deck should be in range, and a $12$ card deck might not even be terribly difficult.  The hope, to stress, is that you will recognize the optimal strategy and you can use that to, at a minimum, design a good proxy.

Comment: Side note:  you want to be careful about competitive strategies as that might lead to a different optimization.  If I'm competing, I might prefer a game with a high probability of very high scores to a game with a lower variance, even if the latter game has a higher mean.

Comment: @DavidClyde  The rules permit you to discard cards.

Comment: Please don't leave clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it contains all relevant information and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and then flag comments as 'no longer needed'.